# File upload - video validation

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

how can I check if a file uploaded to my server by a standard html upload is a video file?

I think file extension and mime checks are not useful as these could be faked. I tried using this script and it partially works, but for some reason it doesn't seem to validate wmv and mp4 formats.

http://mynkow.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/how-to-validate-video-file.html

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: If you mean that it is a video file that could actually play, an idea could be to exec() an external program that does this for you. (Tries to encode and outputs if it can manage to encode it. No matter the headings, the data inside could be corrupted, and PHP isn't a fast language for traversing huge files...)

Comment: no, I want to know that a video is actually a video, eg. the user didn't just rename a file to a video extension.

Comment: Yes, but what if the user did edit a video file and just keep the declarations of the video in the top of the file. The file isn't really a video file, it just has the declarations for one...

Answer (score 0):

Short of actually playing the video and seeing for yourself and  you **absolutely** needed to validate the video then I would use something like FFmpeg. More specificity a tool within FFMpeg called FFprobe - which even better it is free.

"FFprobe is a is a simple multimedia stream analyzer."

http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Main-options

There is a switch '-show_format' which looks promising

I haven't actually used FFprobe so it is theoretical however I have written C# to use FFMpeg to encode 1080p videos into multiple bitrates for web streaming and it does the job very well.

```
ffprobe -show_format [input_file]
```

Hope this helps :)